# Incorrect day of week showing in input date field

Tags: javascript, date, input

I have some code on a website which isn't playing by 'my' rules.

The code:

```
<script>
function do_date()
  {
    v=document.getElementById('date').value;
    n=v.split('-');
    y=n[0];
    m=n[1];
    d=n[2];
    var g=new Date(d,m,y);
    var weekday=new Array(7);
    weekday[0]="Sunday";
    weekday[1]="Monday";
    weekday[2]="Tuesday";
    weekday[3]="Wednesday";
    weekday[4]="Thursday";
    weekday[5]="Friday";
    weekday[6]="Saturday";
    booking_date=d+'/'+m+'/'+y;
    bd=y+''+m+''+d;
    wd=weekday[g.getDay()]
    document.getElementById('viewdate').innerHTML=wd+' '+booking_date;
  }
</script>

<input type="date" id="date" name="date" value="" onchange="do_date()" style="width:150px;" />
```

the variable **`wd`** returns 5 for Friday 5th July 2013, but on Monday the 8th July 2013 it returns 2 in fact consecutive days from the 1st July to the 31st of July 2013 return the following:

```
g.getDay() log=0,1,2,4,5,6,0,2,3,5,0,1,2,3,5,6,0,1,3,4,5,0,2,3,4,6,0,1,2
```

which displays the days in a very strange order

Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,<s>Wednesday</s>,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,<s>Monday</s>,Tuesday etc.

I have obviously done something wrong, but for the life of me I can not work it out.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it :)

Comment: Add logs to find out what is g.getDay() returning for the days where u are getting wrong results.

Comment: the days that are not really missing, they are just skipped, as you can see by the list of comma separated numbers in the question.

Comment: Date constructor should be `new Date(y,m,d)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating wrong the date variable. Look the syntax of the constructor (from [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)):

```
new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, month, day [hour, minute, second, millisecond]);
```

Notice that the month has to be a value between 0 and 11.
So in your code:

```
var g=new Date(y, m - 1, d);
```

Comment: also as well as getting the Y & d mixed up, I forgot the 0 - 11 for the months so `var g=new Date(y, m-1, d);` so no wonder really! Thank you so much