# How to return the correct day of the week given a date - year month and day

Tags: javascript, date

just to simplify my question i have this following code

```
var date = new Date( 2015 , 10 , 16 );

//print the day of the week on console
console.log( date.getDay() ); //prints 1
```

as far as i understand it should have printed 5 since it is a Friday not Monday but it is not , what could be the problem or am i not comprehending the date object?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect day of week showing in input date field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448651/incorrect-day-of-week-showing-in-input-date-field)

Comment: try `console.log(date);` just before your `console.log( date.getDay() );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the month portion of the `Date` constructor is `0`-based. (See [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date))

> **month**
>
> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

You can see this if you were to construct the date in the JavaScript console:

```
new Date( 2015 , 10 , 16 )
> Mon Nov 16 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Comment: also getDay() returns values from 0 to 6 based on US calendar (Sunday is first day). Link [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp)

Comment: being more explicit, this means you are not looking at Oct 16 but Nov 16 (which indeed, is a Monday)

Comment: @kikyalex, good point, although OP did mention that it should have printed 5 for Friday which is correct.  But yes, Sunday would be `0`, not `7`.

Comment: ohhh i see it makes sense now thank you guys :) haha i don't know how i could have missed this when reading the doc